# Why is app group showing red on my iOS project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, share

My app using extension so it need app group. But when I config manual singing, app groups is showing red. I don't know what's wrong? I can still build and run my app. I'm using Xcode 11
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just refresh it. I've solved in that way.

Answer (score 2):

For using App Groups an Apple Developer Account is needed. It looks like you're not signed in.

If you already have a developer account, try to sign in. If not you will need to create one.

If this doesn't fix your error you can register your App Groups manually in the [iOS Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/account/). Go to "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles", select "Identifiers", select your app, activate App Groups and select the groups you want to use.

Comment: I do not want to use automatic signing. I'm using manual signing with certificate and provisioning. Do I need create app group in apple developer website ?

Comment: Yes. You need to add register the app group in the iOS Developer Center

Comment: I updated my answer. Try following the steps and it might solve your problem.

Comment: @sonvuhwg Did it work for you after creating a group? I am facing the same issue. I have created and activated group, re-created profile, but still showing it in red

Comment: @PlusInfosys yeah group is still working.lol